# How to retrieve platform event received in last 5 min or based on custom field catchKey__c?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, platform-event, empapi

We are going to use platform event for our API response which will be directly consumed using empAPI,

Just have few question

- can we retrieve specific event other than replayId field ?
- Can we retrieve all event occurred in last 5 min ?
- Anyway platform catch can be retrieved in client layer?
- Is there any other way in salesforce we retrieve data without hitting server layer ?

Answer (score 2):

> can we retrieve specific event other than replayId field ?

No.

> Can we retrieve all event occurred in last 5 min ?

No. You can retrieve all events still available (replayId = -2), new events (replayId = -1), or from a specific event ID (replayId >= 0).

> Anyway platform catch can be retrieved in client layer?

I presume you mean "cache," and no, there's no option for this, as there isn't a cache to get events from. They come from the server.

> Is there any other way in salesforce we retrieve data without hitting server layer ?

No, the events come from the server.

---

I'm not sure what you're hoping to do, but it sounds like you need to reevaluate your solution path. Please read about the [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and then consider asking about your "X" instead of the solution "Y" that you're trying to solve.